# How to extract channel POD-type from a boost::gil homogeneous pixel type?

Tags: c++, image, graphics, boost, boost-gil

I have a class templated on `<PIXEL>`, assumed to be one of `boost::gil`'s pixel types (for now, only either `gray8_pixel_t` or `gray16_pixel_t`, and I only expect to support homogeneous pixel types e.g `rgb8_pixel_t` in future).

The class needs to get hold of `unsigned char` or `unsigned short` as appropriate to the pixel type; I assume this is buried somehwere in the pixel class, but none of `PIXEL::value_type`, `PIXEL::channel_type` or `PIXEL::channel_type::value type` seems to be what I want.

What's the trick ?

(I could of course use type-indirection via some template-specialized helper structs to get this info:

```
template <typename PIXEL> struct types_for
  {};
template <> struct types_for<boost::gil::gray8_pixel_t>
  {typedef unsigned char channel_type;};
template <> struct types_for<boost::gil::gray16_pixel_t>
  {typedef unsigned short channel_type;};
```

but surely GIL must provide something equivalent already, if I could just find it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha.. this seems to do the trick:

```
typename boost::gil::channel_type<PIXEL>::type
```